# Set building unordered pairs in set theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The definition of an unordered pair seems weird to me. The following set builder notation is used to create a class of an unordered pair that may or may not be a set.
$$ \{x|x=a \ \ \lor \ \ x=b\} $$
The way I understand it is that there is a bound that contains the bounds of $a$ or $b$. This means when $x = a$, it is added as an element to the class that makes up the unordered pair. Then when $x = b$, it is also added as an element to the class.

The definition of $\lor$ also means that $x = a$ and $x = b$ can be true at the same time. This part confuses me, because both terms can be true. This means that $a = b$ though, so I am not sure my understanding is correct. If $a=b$ satisfies the the well formed formula $x=a \ \ \lor \ \ x=b$ then it must become an element of the class, no?

I am using the definition of disjunction defined in this truth table
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline A & B & A \lor B \\\hline
  0 & 0 & F \\\hline
  0 & 1 & T\\\hline
  1 & 0 & T\\\hline
  1 & 1 & T \\\hline
\end{array}
$$

Perhaps the $\lor$ used in the definition is defined like this?
$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|}
\hline A & B & A \lor B \\\hline
  0 & 0 & F \\\hline
  0 & 1 & T\\\hline
  1 & 0 & T\\\hline
  1 & 1 & F \\\hline
\end{array}
$$
In the book it just says $\lor$ is disjunction, so I don't know.

Comment: The set $\{x|x=a\vee x=b\}$ can be one of two sets: (i) $\{x|x=a\}$ (when $a=b$) or (ii) $\{x|x=a\ \mathbb{xor}\ x=b\}$ (when $a\ne b$)

Comment: That makes sense, but I thought when building a set from a well formed formula that you added all elements that made the formula true. This means $a=b$ always has to be true because it satisfies $$ \{x|x=a \ \ \lor \ \ x=b\} $$ Is my understanding of set building wrong? Is any set that satisfies the well formed formula a valid set? This means a set built from a well formed formula could be any number of sets as long as it satisfies the formula?

Comment: There's a distinction between bound and unbound variables. The elements $a,b$ are unbound by the formula. They can be anything. The condition is on $x$ not $a,b$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, an unordered pair $\{a,b\}$ is just a 2-element subset of a set $A$ with $a,b\in A$.
In view of sets, $\{a,b\} = \{b,a\}$.

E.g., $\{1,1\} = \{1\}$ is not a 2-element subset.

Comment: Unless $a=b$, in which case it has one element.

Comment: As I said, 2-element subsets.

Comment: $\{1,1\}$ has *one* element.

Comment: But its not a 2-element set.

Comment: That's what's confusing the asker.

Comment: Does this mean that any bound variables are not actually elements of a set? As in, $x$ is not an element of the unordered pair $$ \{x|x=a \ \ \lor \ \ x=b\} $$ That x is just a bound around the elements?

Comment: What is confusing me is that there are 3 conditions in which the well formed formula could be true. One where only $x=a$ and $x!=b$, another where $x!=a$ and $x=b$, and then one where $x=a$ and $x=b$ and therefore $a=b$. This means x can be one free variable at a time, but the set has two elements. So I think I'm not sure how to build sets given a well formed formula.

Comment: @JohnGlen Does the notation $\{x:\mbox{$x$ is an even natural number}\}$ cause the same sort of confusion? This is a notation for the class of all even natural numbers. The idea is that $\{x:P(x)\}$ is the class of all objects that satisfy the property $P.$ So $\{x:x=a\lor x=b\}$  is the collection of all objects that are equal to $a$ or equal to $b.$ (And we do want the inclusive or, since if we used the exclusive or in the case where $a=b$, the class would be empty, since any set equal to $a$ would also equal $b$ and satisfy both clauses.)

Comment: That clears it up for me. Thank you!

Comment: If you want to put your comment in an answer, I can accept it.